# Spark doesn't seem to call hasNext when iterating through RDD iterators and a limit is applied

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a custom `RDD` in Spark (using Scala) which is responsible for buffering in a stream from a database connection.

When the compute function of the `RDD` is called, I establish a connection to the database, and return an iterator over the stream that I get back.

The problem is that I'm not sure where to close my connection to the database as Spark doesn't seem to have a mechanism to tell me when it's done with the iterator.

Initially I put the cleanup code in the 'hasNext' of the iterator that I return, cleaning up when the end of the iterator is returned.

The problem with this is that when I perform a query with a limit, Spark will not iterate to the end of the iterator, so `hasNext` is never called at the right time.

I can confirm this with the following snippet from `SparkPlan::getByteArrayRdd` (which is the path that my `RDD` is read from when a limit is applied):

```
while (iter.hasNext && (n < 0 || count < n)) {
  val row = iter.next().asInstanceOf[UnsafeRow]
  out.writeInt(row.getSizeInBytes)
  row.writeToStream(out, buffer)
  count += 1
}
```

What mechanisms does Spark provide for custom RDDs to cleanup their resources?

Comment: I suspect what your doing is outside the realm of what Spark is made for. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072893/how-to-create-spark-rdd-from-an-iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TaskContext` that is passed to the `compute` function has an `addTaskCompletionListener` method whose [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.TaskContext) says:

> Adds a (Java friendly) listener to be executed on task completion.
> This will be called in all situations - success, failure, or
> cancellation. Adding a listener to an already completed task will
> result in that listener being called immediately.
>
> An example use is for HadoopRDD to register a callback to close the input stream.
>
> Exceptions thrown by the listener will result in failure of the task.

Sounds to me like that's exactly where you should be closing the DB connection!

Comment: Thanks this works, just as a warning to anyone else who stumbles across this: you cannot really throw an exception from the TaskCompleteListener call as the normal exception handling from spark does not apply, instead your exception will be absorbed into a TaskCompleteListenerException, which is a private type, and there is no clean way to get your exception back.